# custom prefix discord.py, json file

Tags: python, json, discord.py, prefix

I have looked at all the turorials, all the forums, and they all say the same thing about a custom prefix for a discord bot.
I've tried it and it doesnt work.
I've EVEN tried to copy-paste the code and changing the names.
idk what to do now, here's my code:

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix, help_command = None)
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands = True)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    activity = discord.Game(name="!help", type=3)
    await client.change_presence(activity=activity)
    print('online !')

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '!'

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

and here's my error message:

```
Ignoring exception in on_guild_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ethom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ethom\PycharmProjects\discord\rocket_bot\rocket.py", line 32, in on_guild_join
    prefixes = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\ethom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\ethom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\ethom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\ethom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered my own question.
It says that the json file isn't found but in fact, it's not a code problem.
It's a file problem, I have deleted the `__pycache__` file and it suddenly worked correctly.
So, my conclusion is that you have to have no directories in your bot folder.

so, have a nice day ! I hope my response worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases your json.load - JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) error is due to :

1. non-JSON conforming quoting
2. XML/HTML output (that is, a string starting with <), or
3. incompatible character encoding

Ultimately the error tells you that at the very first position the string already doesn't conform to JSON.

Try to debug to verify the content of the file you reading :

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        #Verify the content is really "{}"
        print(f.read())
        prefixes = json.load(f)
        
    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '!'

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

If this verification don't pass, you will need to specify the fix path of your 'prefixes.json' as 'complete_path/prefixes.json' to make sure the correct file is read.

You can also try, if it's not a path problem, to change the encoding when you read the file:

```
 with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
      prefixes = json.loads(f.read().encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: on the json file it just has

{}

Comment: If you want a simply custom prefix for all user, you need to change :

    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

If you want to define a custom prefix for each user, you will need at the begining to define a default prefix and after add a command to change manually the prefix, which could be in fact stored in a JSON file.

Comment: and, can you send the code please ? because I did'nt get all of what you said XD

Comment: What do you want to do exactly it is not clear for me ? Custom prefix for what or who ? I will edit my response with a functionnal code after.

Comment: ok, i want to do a custom prefix for my bot, customizable by a command: !prefix (newprefix); and the prefix can be different for every server.
like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrHbGhem6I4&t=533s

Comment: Your error appears when you try to connect the bot at your server right ?

Comment: yeah thats it .

Comment: more of a problem, when i did the verification, it didnt't even print the file

Comment: Try to put a fix path when you want to open the file. Or you can specify which repository you are currently working with import os; os.chdir(path)

Comment: and what is it returning exactly ?

Comment: i did that: `os.chdir('prefixes.json')` and it does nothing...

Comment: well id does something, that: Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ethom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ethom\PycharmProjects\discord\rocket_bot\rocket.py", line 28, in on_ready
    os.chdir('prefixes.json')
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] Invalid directory name: 'prefixes.json'

Comment: i did `print(os.path.exists('prefixes.json'))` and it retruned a True.
so, the problem comes from another thing... :'(

Comment: `os.chdir("prefixes.json")` can't work since you put a file name. You need to put the complete path as "C:\Users\ethom\...\" to use this command. `print(os.path.exists('prefixes.json'))` => Ok good to know, the problem could be an encoding problem. Please refer to the end of my answer and try this solution.

Comment: why don't you simply use json.load(path)?

Comment: Because if it's not a path problem, it is probably encoding problem. You can also do :  `with open('prefixes.json', 'r',  encoding='utf-8') as f:
      prefixes = json.load(f)`

Comment: because they don't say that in the video

Comment: @vachmara, I did know it couldn't solve the problem, it's just a short way to write it.

Comment: yeah but where do I put json.load(path) ? and what do I write more ? because i dont thinks this is going to be all of it XD